# GCC options with two dashes

Tags: c, gcc

What is the reason for some gcc options to start with two dashes? Are single and double dash interchangeable? For example, https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html lists `-specs=file`, but [exit.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_exit' when using arm-none-eabi-gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419782/exit-c-text0x18-undefined-reference-to-exit-when-using-arm-none-eabi-gcc) refers to `--specs=nosys.specs`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899587/why-does-do-gcc-and-other-tools-not-follow-the-gnu-command-options-conventio

Comment: The number of dashes is not optional, you need to use them as GCC wants them. The rule of thumb is: one dash for short options (one letter) and two for long options (words). However, asking for _reasons_ why some long options have only one dash is probably futile here. You might want to ask GCC's developers.

Comment: @thebusybee I was hoping for interchangeability and backwards compatibility being the reason. Are you saying that `-specs=file` is incorrect?

Comment: Why not just try each alternative? GCC will react accordingly. ;-)

Comment: FWIW: I've just noticed my `--std=...` flag (with two hyphens) was accepted all right (despite `-std` being the documented form).